# Is this averaged exponential sum over primes small infinitely often?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, exponential-sums

Do there exist infinitely many positive integers $N$ such that

$$\sum_{\substack{N/2 \leq q \leq N \\ a/q \notin \mathbb{Z}}} \left|\sum_{1 \leq p \leq N} \exp(2\pi i p a/q) \right|\leq |a|^{o(1)} N^{1+o(1)}
\quad \text{ for all non-zero } a \in \mathbb{Z}?
$$
In the sums, $q$ is an integer and $p$ is a prime.

Some Intuition: By "randomness of primes", for fixed $q$ and $a$, the inner sum should behave like a random walk on $\mathbb{C}$, hence it should be near the origin for infinitely many "times" $N$. Incidentally, I would be interested to see if this intuition can be made rigorous. That is, given $q$, $a$, and $\epsilon>0$, can it be proved that the inner sum is bounded by $\epsilon$ for infinitely many $N$? I haven't been able to work it out myself.

This question is inspired by the comments on the accepted answer to the question [An Exponential Sum Restricted to Primes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260624/an-exponential-sum-restricted-to-primes).